# How can I delete specific Lambda versions using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have a Lambda with 30 versions. I want to delete Lambda versions 1-25 inclusive.

How can I do this using the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 14):

This deletes all Lambda versions from 1 to 25.

It loops inclusively over the 1-25 range & executes [`aws lambda delete-function`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/delete-function.html) appending the version number to the function name, indicating the specific version to be deleted.

Substitute `MyLambdaFunctionName` for your function name.

```bash
functionName='MyLambdaFunctionName'
for i in {1..25}
do
    echo "Deleting $functionName version $i"
    aws lambda delete-function --function-name $functionName:$i
done
```

Comment: If you add `--no-cli-pager`, it will run without opening the text editor between every delete command (which requires you to press the "q" key on each loop)

Comment: Doesn't need the argument on Linux here today

Comment: The cli-pager one